# Java Sound API MP3 encoding fails

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I try to encode wav files using the Java Sound API, but this exception occurs:

```
exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported conversion: MPEG1L3 from PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

Via Maven I provide following dependencies, like the MP3 SPI.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>tritonus-share</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mp3spi</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>vorbisspi</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Currently, according to several online sources I try to encode an wav file to mp3 with the following way / code:

```
private final AudioFormat.Encoding MPEG1L3 = new AudioFormat.Encoding("MPEG1L3");
private final AudioFileFormat.Type MP3 = new AudioFileFormat.Type("MP3", "mp3");

public void play() {

    try {

        // Get Audio Stream
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("input.wav")))
        );

        inputStream = getConvertedStream(inputStream, MPEG1L3);

        AudioSystem.write(inputStream, this.MP3, new File("out.mp3"));

    } catch(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }


}


private AudioInputStream getConvertedStream(
        AudioInputStream sourceStream,
        AudioFormat.Encoding targetEncoding) throws Exception {

    AudioFormat sourceFormat = sourceStream.getFormat();

    logger.info("Input format: " + sourceFormat);

    AudioInputStream targetStream = null;
    if (!AudioSystem.isConversionSupported(targetEncoding, sourceFormat)) {

        AudioFormat intermediateFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                sourceFormat.getSampleRate(),
                16,
                sourceFormat.getChannels(),
                2 * sourceFormat.getChannels(), // frameSize
                sourceFormat.getSampleRate(),
                false);

        if (AudioSystem.isConversionSupported(intermediateFormat, sourceFormat)) {
            sourceStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(intermediateFormat, sourceStream);
        }
    }

    return AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetEncoding, sourceStream);
}
```

I hope for answers, why it does not work! :(

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Does an exception throw? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add the occurring exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported conversion: MPEG1L3 from PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian`

Comment: mp3spi only supports reading MP3, it does not support encoding an MP3

Comment: That sounds bad. Is there any other Java Sound SPI for mp3, which also supports encoding of mp3?